# "I'm bound where my feet take me, and heart where my wills"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In Sandman #38, there is a moment when two strangers meet on a road and the following dialogue happens:

> "Where are you bound, young peddler?" asks the man.
>
> "I'm bound where my feet take me, and heart where my wills," said the young man.

[image: Sandman #38's dialogue]

What does the clause "*...and heart where my wills*" mean? In particular, what are the meanings of the words *heart* and *wills* in this context?

Comment: *and heart where my wills* is almost certainly a mistake, and should have been *and where my heart wills*.  If it's not a mistake it's very non-standard and I (native BrE speaker) have no idea what it means.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Agreed, as another native BrE speaker. It has no meaning of which I am aware.

Comment: I would say the mistake is in the use of *my* and that it should be *and heart where **it** wills*.

Answer (score -1):

An expanded and more clear version of the sentence could be:

**I am bound where my feet take me, and my heart is bound where my wills take me.**

I hope this helps to understand the meaning.

Such shortenings are quite common in written English, but this one does seem to be a bit unclear and awkward.

Comment: Thanks for the ingenious solution to an intractable problem. But I don't buy it. "My wills" is almost unknown - the iWeb corpus has only 26 instances, and many of them are in a different sense. All the examples of "my wills" in this sense seem to be in reference to a single biblical verse (Acts XIII 22).